# Why using a template's parameter's type member as a return type of a function works without typname keyword but in other places it doesn't work?

Tags: c++, templates, typename, type-members

As we know we must perpend `typename` before using a Type Member of a Template Type Parameter because without it the compiler doesn't know whether we are accessing a Type member or using a static data member because the fact that the definition of the class template is not yet present (instantiation)

```
   template <typename T>
   void foo()
   {
       T::type x{}; // error: need a typename
       typename T::type y{}; // ok
   }
```

Until here it is OK but what about this problem I've discovered:

```
template <typename C_>
C_::value_type get_sum(C_ const& c) // no need to typename?!
{
    C_::value_type sum0{}; // errorL: need to typename keyword
    typename C_::value_type sum{};
    for(auto const& i : c)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

As you can see inside the function template body the compiler complains about missing the keyword `typename` but using it as a return type it doesn't complain? can someone explain why?

Comment: because in the return type can only be a type.

Comment: An easier way to handle this is to declare the return type as `auto` instead, so the return type is deduced as the same type as `sum` whatever it happens to be.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably compiling in C++20 mode. The [Down with typename!](https://wg21.link/p0634) paper allows `typename` to be omitted in certain contexts. One of these contexts is when the type name is "a *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *simple-declaration* or a *function-definition* in namespace scope". In the case of the `get_sum` function definition, which (I assume) is at namespace scope, the *decl-specifier-seq* is `C_::value_type`, consisting of a single *decl-specifier*, thus this *decl-specifier* is allowed to omit `typename`. Also, if `get_sum` were defined at class scope, it would be covered by the *member-declaration* bullet point, and thus `typename` would not be required in that case either.

`typename` continues to be required in most block-scope declarations, since for those, there is a possibility that the dependent name may refer to a non-type; the compiler presumes that they are non-types, possibly leading to an error, unless `typename` is used.